# Array of movie clips ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

How would I go about making an array of movie clips?

If you could include an example with the setting of one part of the array, that would be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(untested code)

```
//Create array of movie clips
var someArray:Array = new Array(mc1,mc2,mc3,mc4);

//Access certain movie clip, in this case mc3
someArray[2].visible = false;
```

Also consider using a vector, it is generally faster.

```
//Declare a vector
var someVector:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
//Add movie clips
someVector.push(mc1);
someVector.push(mc2);
someVector.push(mc3);
someVector.push(mc4);
```

To access them I would do it like this:

```
var tempMC:MovieClip = someArray[1]; // or = someVector[1];
tempMC.x = 30;
tempMC.width = 300;
```

or you can just say:

```
MovieClip(someArray[1]).x = 30;
```

or the lazy way as shown on the 2nd line of code above.

Comment: What if I want to access it like a movie clip, does it allow that? like setting its position?